# Relacionamentos com o Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Seguinte, estou modelando a classe de domínio de um sistema e estou com dificuldade para entender certas coisas do `Entity Framework`, então, espero que possam me ajudar, visando que estou seguindo a ideia do `Code First`:

Em um relacionamento de `N` para `M`, fazendo do seguinte jeito, ele irá gerar uma nova tabela automaticamente ou eu terei que fazer isso manualmente? Se manualmente, como faço essa relação?

```
public class Aluno {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Professor> Professores { get; set; }
}

public class Professor {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando este [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) como referência, podem haver dois tipos de configuração.

**Opção 1 - Data Annotation**

```
public class Aluno 
{
   public Aluno()
   {
      Professores = new HashSet<Professor>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Professor> Professores { get; set; }
}

public class Professor 
{    
   public Professor()
   {
      Alunos = new HashSet<Aluno>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
}
```

Neste caso, isso já bastaria e os relacionamentos seriam criados corretamente.

**Opção 2 - Fluent API**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>()
                .HasMany<Professor>(s => s.Professores)
                .WithMany(c => c.Alunos)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("IdAluno");
                            cs.MapRightKey("IdProfessor");
                            cs.ToTable("AlunoProfessor"); // Nome da tabela
                        });
}
```